# Send money from business to customer express checkout

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I'm currently building af website, where a user can buy and sell virtual currency. 
Let's say, that user1 buys 100 points in virtual currency. User2 then might do something for user1, and user1 then transfers the virtual funds to user2. 
User2 then might want to convert those virtual funds into real currency. This is the part I need help with.


Is it possible for me, to transfer paypal funds from my business account, to user2 using the express checkout API, or should I use something else?


Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Express Checkout, you would not be able to achieve this as the payments are simply one-way processes.

You may want to integrate with Adaptive Payments APIs to manage the virtual currencies in your ecosystem. 
In this use case, USER2 could redeem the virtual funds with Implicit Approval Payments Flow, to draw funds from your business account and send to the user.

See integration details here at the [Adaptive Payments Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/) and [API specs](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/)